# How do I set an SSRS Parameter that doesn't have a value to something else?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have an SSRs Report with a parameter that gets information from SQL. If it hasn't found anything, at the moment it  is just empty. Is there anyway to set it such that if it's empty it will return a different value, say "Please Extend Date Ranges" and disable the parameter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you using it to fill it using the SQL and using it for only internal purposes then there is option to make the parameter internal and it will be hidden and it will does not prompt the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make a change to the stored procedure or query that populates the parameter.  Include some logic so that if no results are returned by the query you are using now, it adds a row with the default label you want.

But no, you can't disable the parameter dynamically, I don't believe.